# What is the problem with this python 3 script

Tags: python-3.x, windows, video, stack-overflow, video-compression

I made a script for compressing videos

```
import ffmpeg
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe"['ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -b 800k output.mp4'])
print(result)
```

When I run this an error will come like this-

```
    result = subprocess.run("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe"['ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -b 800k output.mp4'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

What is the solution?

Comment: ```['ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -b 800k output.mp4']``` why is this inside square brackets?

Comment: I put that because I want to add the path `"C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe"`

Comment: Have you read the documentation for that?

Comment: What is documentation

Comment: How does the edited question even related to the original question? Stop editing question post answers. This is not a prank site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be malformed:

```
subprocess.run("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe"['ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -b 800k output.mp4'])
```

I'm pretty sure you just want this:

```
result = subprocess.run(["C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe", "-i", "output.mp4", "-b", "800k",  "output.mp4"])
```

Or perhaps just this:

```
result = subprocess.run("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i output.mp4 -b 800k output.mp4")
```

Also, not sure if it's a good idea to have your input file and output file, `output.mp4` be the same.

Comment: Thanks sir. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Well, look at the argument you tried to pass.  I've insert a line feed to help reading:

```
"C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe"
    ['ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -b 800k output.mp4']
```

The first line is a string.  You followed that with a bracket.  What comes next *must* be a subscript for the string.  What did you *think* you were doing?

Comment: I can't; I don't know what you think this is supposed to be.  Two separate arguments, perhaps?  If so, a comma corrects the problem -- and we close the question as a typo.

Comment: Then also it is showing - `result = subprocess.run("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe"['ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -b 800k output.mp4'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: "Then" what?  The code in your comment is essentially identical to the one in your post.  Did you try the separate arguments I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

`"C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe"['ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -b 800k output.mp4']`
As @Prune has pointed out, the error occurs as you're indexing the string using another string, which is incorrect. The correct way to pass arguments to `subprocess.run` is

`result = subprocess.run("[C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe", 'ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -b 800k output.mp4'])`
If you want to add more arguments, you can do so using positional arguments.

Comment: Please read the official documentation in such cases, they'll almost always help you out